# can't pass TARGETDIR in CustomActionsData

Tags: visual-studio

I have a VS2010 setup project. I want to pass the TARGETDIR parameter to the Install custom action. I add /TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]" to the CustomData property of the custom action. But when I run the setup project I get System.IO.FileNotFound exception. What's wrong?

Comment: CustomActionData property, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write /TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR] " . Some say that /TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]\" also works. God this is stupid.

Comment: This is because TARGETDIR is resolved to a path ended with a backslash (for example "C:\test\"). That backslash escapes the last quote, so you get an invalid argument ("C:\test\\). If you add a space or a second backslash the quote is no longer escaped.