# How to pass TARGETDIR into CustomActionsData?

Tags: visual-studio, custom-action

I have a VS2010 setup project. I want to pass the `TARGETDIR` parameter to the `Install` custom action. `/TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]"` and `/TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]\"` are wrong.

So, what is the right method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't pass TARGETDIR in CustomActionsData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602875/cant-pass-targetdir-in-customactionsdata)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the brackets you must include quotation marks and a trailing backslash:

> /name="[TARGETDIR]\"

MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: NO. I try it so ,but make no different.    there is some words:  Hello,

After migrating from VS2008 post-build-events seem to fail in VS2010 because the macros TargetPath and TargetDir are wrong defined in VS2010.

TargetPath and TargetDir seem to ignore the a customized value of "Output File".

For intance, we set the "Output File" to "..\lib\mylib.lib", but the TargetPath is still "Release\mylib.lib" which is bogus.
  

I hope, that this will be fixed in 2010, or am i missing something there?

Comment: OK ！ /TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]\" is right! maybe Full path name must be in Double quotes some time.