# installing multiple exe's at same time in window from application

Tags: c#, setup-project

I have two different windows application projects. I want that at the time of installation both will install together in same folder like one exe is installed.After installation both will work separately.There is an xml file which will be update by one project which have forms and another exe will use it which does not contain any form,just show the notify icon.Is it possible to create a setup file which will install both the exe's together? how do I give the path of the xml file?

Comment: What type of installer are you planning to use?  We really need some more information before you can get a good answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Now, what is your actual question?

Comment: I am using the visual studio installer. My question is how do I do this? how to merge both project in one installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SetupProject to do it

Add setup project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.80).aspx

Add primary outputs of both applications to it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11b431t(v=vs.80).aspx

If you want to place your xml file in your installation folder, there are permission issues to resolve if you want to change it later when your applications are running (usually admin privilages are needed), so you can't just add it to your setup project (that will only copy it to your installation path).

But after adding it to your setup project, you can copy your xml file to the location of your choice. Path of the xml file can be set using environment paths, for example `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

You can do it using a separate little console project that contains **Installer** class, where you copy your file and generally do additional things that need to be done during installation :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx

[How to pass TARGETDIR into CustomActionsData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753054/how-to-pass-targetdir-into-customactionsdata)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5821/All-about-Installers-Customizing-Windows-and-Web-s

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz(VS.80).aspx

You can use **TARGETDIR** to get your installation path in yoour installerr class (just google it or use the link above, it's explained well there)

Then add your installer project's primary output to CustomActions in your SetupProject.